# Unable to get correct Output from MySQL Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `create_Publisher`(IN userGuid VARCHAR(36), IN pubEmail VARCHAR(120), IN passwd VARCHAR(120), IN pubGuid VARCHAR(36), IN pubName VARCHAR(120), IN cat VARCHAR(500), OUT isSuccess TINYINT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    SET isSuccess = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO users (guid,email,password,role) VALUES (userGuid,pubEmail,passwd,'publisher');
    SELECT @userid := id FROM users WHERE email=pubEmail;
    INSERT INTO publisher (guid,name,cat,status,user_id) VALUES (pubGuid,pubName,cat,'pause',@userid);

    IF `_rollback` THEN
        SET isSuccess = 0;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SET isSuccess = 1;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This is the procedure I am working on. The purpose is to create a new Publisher. Whether the new publisher is created or not, that is being known by isSuccess variable, which is an OUT parameter. It is always giving me 0, even if publisher is being created.

I am using MySQL 5.7.12, working on MySQL WorkBench.
Checking the procedure via below lines:

```
CALL create_Publisher('U_GUID20','r@r.com','Hahaha','P_GUID20','ThePublisher',NULL, @isSucess);

SELECT @isSuccess;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try from the MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION()//
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.12    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `publisher`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_Publisher`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    ->   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `guid` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ->   `email` VARCHAR(120),
    ->   `password` VARCHAR(120),
    ->   `role` VARCHAR(12)
    -> )//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publisher` (
    ->   `guid` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(120),
    ->   `cat` VARCHAR(500),
    ->   `status` VARCHAR(12),
    ->   `user_id` VARCHAR(12)
    -> )//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `create_Publisher`(
    ->   `userGuid` VARCHAR(36),
    ->   `pubEmail` VARCHAR(120),
    ->   `passwd` VARCHAR(120),
    ->   `pubGuid` VARCHAR(36),
    ->   `pubName` VARCHAR(120),
    ->   `cat` VARCHAR(500),
    ->   OUT `isSuccess` TINYINT
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` := 1;
    ->   SET `isSuccess` := 1;
    ->   START TRANSACTION;
    -> 
    ->   INSERT INTO `users` (
    ->     `guid`,
    ->     `email`,
    ->     `password`,
    ->     `role`
    ->   ) VALUES (
    ->     `userGuid`,
    ->     `pubEmail`,
    ->     `passwd`,
    ->     'publisher'
    ->   );
    ->   SELECT @`userid` := `id`
    ->   FROM `users`
    ->   WHERE `email` = `pubEmail`;
    -> 
    ->   INSERT INTO `publisher` (
    ->     `guid`,
    ->     `name`,
    ->     `cat`,
    ->     `status`,
    ->     `user_id`
    ->   ) VALUES (
    ->     `pubGuid`,
    ->     `pubName`,
    ->     `cat`,
    ->     'pause',
    ->     @`userid`
    ->   );
    -> 
    ->   IF `_rollback` THEN
    ->     SET `isSuccess` := 0;
    ->       ROLLBACK;
    ->   ELSE
    ->     SET `isSuccess` := 1;
    ->     COMMIT;
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `create_Publisher`(
    ->   'U_GUID20',
    ->   'r@r.com',
    ->   'Hahaha',
    ->   'P_GUID20',
    ->   'ThePublisher',
    ->   NULL,
    ->   @`isSucess`
    -> );
+-------------------+
| @`userid` := `id` |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`isSucess`;
+-------------+
| @`isSucess` |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `guid`,
    ->   `email`,
    ->   `password`,
    ->   `role`
    -> FROM
    ->   `users`;
+----------+---------+----------+-----------+
| guid     | email   | password | role      |
+----------+---------+----------+-----------+
| U_GUID20 | r@r.com | Hahaha   | publisher |
+----------+---------+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `guid`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `cat`,
    ->   `status`,
    ->   `user_id`
    -> FROM
    ->   `publisher`;
+----------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
| guid     | name         | cat  | status | user_id |
+----------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
| P_GUID20 | ThePublisher | NULL | pause  | 1       |
+----------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- FAIL
mysql> CALL `create_Publisher`(
    ->   'U_GUID21',
    ->   'r1@r.com',
    ->   'Hahaha1',
    ->   NULL,           -- <<<< SQLEXCEPTION >>>>
    ->   'ThePublisher1',
    ->   NULL,
    ->   @`isSucess`
    -> );
+-------------------+
| @`userid` := `id` |
+-------------------+
|                 2 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`isSucess`;
+-------------+
| @`isSucess` |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `guid`,
    ->   `email`,
    ->   `password`,
    ->   `role`
    -> FROM
    ->   `users`;
+----------+---------+----------+-----------+
| guid     | email   | password | role      |
+----------+---------+----------+-----------+
| U_GUID20 | r@r.com | Hahaha   | publisher |
+----------+---------+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `guid`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `cat`,
    ->   `status`,
    ->   `user_id`
    -> FROM
    ->   `publisher`;
+----------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
| guid     | name         | cat  | status | user_id |
+----------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
| P_GUID20 | ThePublisher | NULL | pause  | 1       |
+----------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In your stored procedure, you can change the following:

```sql
.
.
.
DECLARE `userid` INT UNSIGNED;
.
.
.

/*
SELECT @`userid` := `id`
FROM `users`
WHERE `email` = `pubEmail`;
*/
SET `userid` := LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO `publisher` (
  `guid`,
  `name`,
  `cat`,
  `status`,
  `user_id`
) VALUES (
  `pubGuid`,
  `pubName`,
  `cat`,
  'pause',
  `userid`
);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you please point out the error? Is the error due to WorkBench?

Comment: @gagangupt16: What version of MySQL Workbench are you using?. I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3.6 and can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using WorkBench 6.0.8

Comment: @gagangupt16: Using MySQL Workbench 6.0.8 and MySQL Server 5.7.12, I can't reproduce the problem, the script above works without problem.

Comment: @gagangupt16: Beware typo. `@isSucess` != `@isSuccess`.